# Get all indexPaths of a collection view

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, uicollectionview

I need to get all indexPaths of a collection view, visible and invisible, so I can force them to load with `CollectionView.ReloadItems(IndexPaths[] indexPaths)`.

This is the only way I can think of forcing to load all indexPaths. I saw how to do it in Swift, but I can't do it in C#:

```
var indexPaths: [NSIndexPath] = []
for s in 0..<collectionView.numberOfSections() {
    for i in 0..<collectionView.numberOfItemsInSection(s) {
        indexPaths.append(NSIndexPath(forItem: i, inSection: s))
    }
}
```

I know it is not recommended to load all cells, but for this case there's no other way.

Edit: The project is too large and the problem could be anywhere, also I'm not allowed to share sourcecode. I can tell you my problem without showing code, we have a container view that has a list of cells that have a checkbox, over the container view there's a button that's supossed to check all the cells when pressed, problem is the cells that are not loaded yet, they don't get binded so they don't change when the button is pressed unless the user has scrolled down first and the cells are loaded, the bind is created when they are loaded (when the method awake from nib is called), we're using mvvmcross too.

Comment: 1. No, there is no reason to reload all rows using `reloadItems`. 2. Why not use `reloadData()`?

Comment: Are you sure it reloads all data? Or only visible. If it is suposed to load all data then there might be another bug in the code, it is a large project.

Comment: Why don't you post a question about the actual issue you are trying to solve instead of posting a question about implementing a (possibly incorrect) solution you have come up with for your actual problem? See [What is the XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Please read my edit